# Are there any alternatives to `chntpw`?

Tags: windows, users

`chntpw` is a Linux program that can be used to change user passwords etc. on a Windows installation.

It claims that it "*Should handle both 32 and 64 bit windows and
all version from NT3.x to Win8.1*".

What about Windows 10?

Even if it does work on that, are there other, possibly better, programs (e.g. to add a new user)?

Answer (score 0):

according to [it's wikipedia-article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chntpw) and [this](https://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/how-to-use-linux-to-reset-a-windows-password/) howto, you can only blank the password on windows 10 and then set a new password inside windows

EDIT: as a non-linux alternative, the second solution from [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/222262/how-to-reset-your-forgotten-password-in-windows-10/) looks promising.